# How to specify a generic dictionary in payload of flask-restplus/flask-restx?

Tags: flask-restplus, flask-restx

I have an API which receives a JSON looking like this

```
{
  "some_key" : [ "v1", "v2" ]
  "another_key" : [ a1, a2, a3, a4 ]
  ...
}
```

So I wanted to define something along these lines

```
dict_model = api.model('ArbitraryDict', {
  fields.String : fields.List(fields.String)
})
```

Which, of course, does not work.

I know how to define a model where the keys are known ahead of time, but I need to support *any* dictionary where keys are strings and values are (homogeneous) arrays of either numbers of strings.

I looked into `api.schema_model` but I am unable to get `flask-restx` to accept anything, not even a plain dictionary.

Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question but, why not use a different structure?

```
[
    {
        "key": "some_key", 
        "value": ["v1", "v2"]
    },
    {
        "key": "another_key", 
        "value": [a1, a2]
    },
]
```